# Windows 11 update destroyed my dual boot. "unknown" root partition

Tags: fedora, boot, partition

i had dual boot with Windows 11 and Fedora. After windows 11 update, i was just greated by this error log on boot:

```
error: ./../grub-core/commands/search.c:315: no such device: b3f77801-d8af-429d-9dcb-f7b1a907cca0. error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem. error: ../../grub-core/commands/search.c:315: no such device: b3f77801-deaf-429d-9dcb-f7b1a907ccae. error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file /EFI/fedora/grubenv' not found.
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unknown filesystem.

Press any key to continue..
```

When i boot to live USB, gparted shows "unknown" partition instead of my Fedora 37 partition
[image: screenshot of my fedora partition from grub]

`fdisk - l` outputs:

```
Disk model: CT500MX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BDDFEC40-FC5C-42C8-AF16-390AC740C578

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2    1085440   1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1290240   1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1323008 593813504 592490497 282.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  593815552 595089407   1273856   622M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb6  595091456 976773119 381681664   182G Linux filesystem
```

I dont even know how to begin in this case, its not just missing GRUB, i cant mount my OS partition.

Comment: What does `file -s /dev/sdb6` say? It's highly unlikely Windows 11 could have done it.

Comment: Did maybe windows insert a partition, which shifted linux partition from /dev/sdb5 to /dev/sdb6? That happened to me with Windows 10. Here is what I had to do: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655027#655027